# Gitosis installation error

Tags: git, gitosis

I am trying to install gitosis on my server but keep getting the error "Username contains not allowed characters"

```
sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/id_rsa.pub
```

with the username "abhinav@115.118.212.234.static-delhi.vsnl.net.in".

Any fix for this?

I am on a Mac and trying to install gitosis on Snow Leopard.

**Update**

I changed the username in the public key to abhinav@vindev.net and it worked. Probably it's a problem with the hyphen sign. After installing I tried this

```
git clone git@vindev.net:gitosis-admin.git
cd gitosis-admin
```

but it fails saying

```
fatal: 'gitosis-admin.git': unable to chdir or not a git archive
```

Any ideas about what I may be doing wrong?

This is the guide I followed: http://nfocipher.com/index.php?op=ViewArticle&articleId=12&blogId=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this related to the public key format, as described in [this thread](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way)?

(I know it refers to a Window installation and you are on a Unix server, but the idea remains valid)

> I figured that `PuttyGen` had generated an SSH2  public key file in a slightly different format, and ‘`git gitosis-init`’ wanted a user name at the beginning, so I went here:

http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4716

> and saw that I could keep the “`--BEGIN…`” and “`--END`” parts, and replace the “`comment: ...`” line (generated by `PuttyGen`) with a line reading:

```
subject: git
```

> And it worked! I got the output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/
```

---

> You can also try to copy just the key, as in [this thread](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=470359):
>
> It's work fine for my ssh-pubkey on rawhide. I assume you have the wrong file
>   format.
>   Try to copy `id_rsa.pub` key only (without comments, etc), run `sudo -H -u gitosis gitosis-init`, paste pubkey, then `^D`.

Comment: I am on a Mac trying to install Gitosis on CentOS. I tried copy/pasting the key but it says sudo: no passwd entry for gitosis!

Comment: Ok. Was using 'gitosis' in the command instead of 'git'. It's still saying Username contains not allowed characters.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. Turns out it was because username started with a number.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think my username started with a number. I'll check again. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. My issue was an '_' in the name of my computer.